# Http GET request with parameters in Okhttp Android Kotlin

Tags: android, http, kotlin, okhttp, http-get

I am trying to process Http GET request with parameters using Okhttp in Android Kotlin.

As there is no GET resource found on documentation and other internet resources didn't work, how can I set GET request in Okhttp with pre defined parameters.

Builder code with lack of GET method

```
val parameter  = "{\"phone\": \"$phone\"}"

val request = Request.Builder().url(weburl)
.header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
.addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
//.method("GET",parameter.toRequestBody())
.build()
```

Output result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8QRs.png)

Comment: "OkHttp Headers.java" a space in your java file name is asking for problems, it does work sometimes but  not guarenteed, try chanign the java file name to someting like "headers.java"

Comment: based on my understanding, are you looking for ```@GET($your_endpoint)```?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to send the `phone` as a query parameter, you should add it to the request URL, not to the request body. You don't need to specify the method: GET is the default. By the way, you can get rid of the `Content-type` header (GET requests, usually, have no content):

```kotlin
val url = weburl.toHttpUrl().newBuilder()
    .addQueryParameter("phone", phone)
    .build()

val request = Request.Builder().url(url)
    .header("User-Agent", "OkHttp Headers.java")
    .header("Accept", "application/json")
    .build()
```

If your requirement is to send a GET request with a request body, than you are out of luck I'm afraid: OkHttp does not support it. Anyways, most likely, it's not what you want (unless you are calling Elasticsearch API...)